# Bash scripting | awk with ariables

Tags: bash, awk, centos

Works:

```
repquota $HOME | awk "{if(\$3 > $MIN && \$3 < $MAX )print}"
```

But if i try insert this to variable it isn't working:

```
VARIABLE=`repquota $FULL_HOME | awk "{if(\$3 > $MIN && \$3 < $MAX )print}"`
```

> awk: {if( > 1572864 &&  < 302118056)print}
>
> awk:      ^ syntax error

Comment: What are FULL_HOME,MAX, and MIN  Did you export all relevant variables?

Comment: Try `export MIN MAX`, and `VARIABLE=$(repquota $FULL_HOME | awk "{if(\$3 > $MIN && \$3 < $MAX )print}")`

Comment: I'm kind of happy that it's more difficult to do the \$" dance than to simply use -v. We have so many security bugs in the world because it's often easier to write unsecure code. bash/awk are not kind with unsecure coders :-). See answer below how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the new command substitution syntax `$(command)`:

```
VARIABLE=$(repquota $FULL_HOME | awk "{if(\$3 > $MIN && \$3 < $MAX )print}")
```

### Explanation

From `man bash`:

```
   When  the  old-style  backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
   retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `,  or  \.   The
   first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command sub‐
   stitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between  the
   parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.
```

When using backslashes, a `\$var` inside a double-quoted string is not scaped, resulting in the value of `$var` being substituted, so `awk` does not see `$3`, as you expected.

You can see it with these commands:

```
var="I am a test string"
echo `echo "\$var"` # output: I am a test string
echo $(echo "\$var") # output: $var
```

Edit: As Ed Morton comments, you should not pass awk variables from shell that way, instead use the `-v` switch of awk:

```
VARIABLE=$(repquota $FULL_HOME | awk -v min="$MIN" -v max="$MAX" '{if($3 > min && $3 < max )print}')
```

Comment: Never use awk that way. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to pass the value of shell variables to awk scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Your bash syntax is way off. You're not quoting variables, wrongly quoting an awk script, and using deprecated backticks. What you seem to be trying to do would be:

```
VARIABLE=$(repquota "$FULL_HOME" | awk -v min="$MIN" -v max="$MAX" '($3>min) && ($3<max)')
```

but since you didn't provide any sample input and expected output it's an untested guess and it's always hard to tell what you DO want from reading a script that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I would put the $(...) as "$(...)" to be whitespace safe. Bonus points for using -v and and very awky patterns :-)

Comment: @Gunstick - thanks. Are you sure you need double quotes in this case though? It's an assignment so globbing and word splitting won't happen AFAIK. Try `x=$(awk 'BEGIN{print "a\tb"}'); echo "$x"`.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong. No quotes needed. If awk spies out multiple lines, and later on you want to count the lines or do something else lines based, using "$VARIABLE" the double quotes will preserve the linefeeds when.